# What should our chatroom be named?

Tags: discussion, chat

Our [lovely chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12851/software-recommendations) is currently sitting there with a terribly generic name: Software Recommendations.

What should we name it?

Comment: Yay, bikeshedding! I actually think the generic name is okay, isn’t it? Call it “Software Recommendations.SE site chat” for now.,

Comment: Ah, *there* it is! #D

Comment: Especially since the site itself has a terribly generic name :)

Answer (score 10):

### Soft wrecks

(ha-ha-only-serious)

Comment: I'm down. Let's do this.

Comment: I suggest adding a "The" at the beginning. Sounds more like a place then.

Comment: Great minds think alike. I made this joke just hours earlier.

Comment: Took me a few secs. After getting the joke: What's the "K" for, Jay... ahem, G?

Answer (score 8):

Thought of this overnight...

#### The Rec Center

It's not perfectly matched to our topic, but it sounds kinda good. Maybe it'll give some people inspiration to come up with something better!

Comment: Like. This is my favorite proposal so far.

Comment: Sounds inviting too (although I also like Software Rex).

Comment: In the meantime [Hardware Recommendations grabbed the name](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/28945/the-rec-center).

Answer (score 3):

### Software Rex

*The meanest, biggest bad ass chat room on the plains.*

[image]

Comment: I like this, but not as a chat room name. A chat room name should evoke a place or an audience (“The Bridge”, “The DMZ”, “Mos Eisley”, “The Hangar”, “The Screening Room”, “Chez Cosette”, …), not a creature.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to make a joke about `swrecs` in reference to Sean Connery on Jeopardy saying "schwords" (like `swords`) for "S Words" when talking about the category of questions pertaining to "S Words". I failed. Couldn't think of anything pithy -- all the pith got stolen by Robert's answer above. Seriously, "Software Rex"? That's a whole mouthful of pith. ;x

I was thinking of the extremely lame, pun-free name `Word of Mouth`. I have to explain it for it to make any sense, so it's probably bad, but once you get it, it kind of tickles. A little. Maybe.

So there are often surveys on registration forms or purchase forms for software online, which ask "How did you hear about us?" or "How did you hear about X product?", and one of the choices is "Word of Mouth".

Well.

It would seem fitting that people would hear about their software *literally* in the "Word of Mouth" channel about this site, or from the site itself, and then go buy that software.

Not funny, right? Oh well. I tried.

Comment: I like `Word of Mouth`,  (although the german equivalent, translates like `Mouthpropaganda`, would be cooler somehow)

Comment: I hope you can refrain from making it [Shreck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shreck) #D Well, the other [Shreck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrek_%28franchise%29) might be not a much better choice...

Answer (score 3):

## Control F

Well known key combination, where Control can have the meaning as in Control Room too. And F can mean multiple things :)

Comment: Like the ship-wrecked computer geek, screaming "F1, F1!" :D

Comment: Ouch, need to correct myself: F7 would be a better fit than F1. Or "F1-F7" for "HelpMe-Find"?

Answer (score 3):

### The Suggestion Box

I can't take credit for this one, someone else came up with it.

Answer (score 2):

## Softwarehouse

Because software, house, and warehouse in one.

Answer (score 2):

## The Warehouse

Because we serve (Soft)Ware<strike>z</strike>**s** and will soon have lots of them.

**Warehouse 101** sounds cool too, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

## Much soft

So fluffy. Very recommended.

This name also means that there is a lot of software around, implying that it is sometimes difficult to find the best match.

(variation on Angelo's answer)

Comment: This is so cheesy, but somehow I love it.

Answer (score 0):

## Fluffy recommends

I just think that Software should have been called Fluffyware in the first place. I mean "soft" is such a boring word, ain't it?