# Software Recommendations chatroom name

Tags: discussion, chat

[Before, Undo asked a question about naming the chatroom](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-should-our-chatroom-be-named). The seemingly most supported proposal was "Soft Wrecks". I understand that it is good to keep it generic, but now that our site is graduating, I think we need a better name for our chatroom.

Should we change our chatroom name now, or still keep it generic?

Answer (score 2):

The name should be changed to "Soft Wrecks", name on which most people seemed to agree at the discussion you linked to.

Gilles comments that the name change was just forgotten, so hopefully it will be changed soon.

Comment: The current name is “Software Recommendations”, not “Soft Wrecks”. We'd forgotten to change the name after the original meta thread had received some attention. Since nobody complained, and there's no momentum here either, we're keeping the generic name so far.

Comment: @Gilles: I did not realize that, thanks! I updated my answer.